# Network Issues Connection to SQL database on MS server

Tags: sql-server, web-server, port, sql, connection

Prior to asking this question, I followed this thread:

[Cannot telnet to SQL Server on port 1433](https://serverfault.com/questions/422622/cannot-telnet-to-sql-server-on-port-1433)

I am attempting to connect to a database on a server distinct from the computer upon which I am running WebMatrix. The server has an inbound connection rule allowing connections through a dynamic port, 55555 (for example).

The SQL Server (Express, 2005) is set to dynamic ports and listens at the port for which the inbound rule is present (this is set in the "IP All" section).

my data source line in the "Server" box in the WebMatrix connection string wizard reads:

55.55.55.55\SQLExpress\database, 55555.

Everything else (UID, password, etc.) is present..

However, I am getting an error message which reads:

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Finally, the site is substantial and has a complicated structure, so I'm positive that running around changing things with respect to the SQL server's settings is a bad idea, so I have to make the status quo work (i.e., switching the port from dynamic to 1433 might not be a good idea, since someone created a rule and set everything up for the dynamic connection already). Is there a step I'm missing that would allow my computer to talk to the database in question?

Also, I tested the connection with Telnet, and it seems like the port isn't open...and yet the firewall has a rule for opening the port in question, and the FTP port works fine (for which there is a more restrictive rule than the SQL port's rule already in place).

Netstat shows that, currently, the server is listening at 0.0.0.0:53054 (my port number). However, when I attempt to connect to the server, located at ip address x (not 0.0.0.0) and port 53054, nothing happens...but the FTP port shows up as 0.0.0.0:21, listening, and that works fine when I connect.

Also, when I telnet to the port (53054) from the server, it works fine. So what is going on here?

Comment: Can connect from the server, can't connect from another computer? Sounds like the firewall rule is wrong.

Comment: Just tried to do it with the firewall disabled; same result.  I am stumped.

Comment: Are you connecting on a LAN, or over a VPN, or between sites? Is there any routing going on where the server might not be able to route replies back to your WebMatrix client? Do you have any firewall/security software on your WebMatrix machine that might deny outbound connections?

Comment: I think I can rule out my home pc because I was able to connect the the ftp port and I tried it on a cell phone hotspot instead of the home network...

The connection is between sites in the sense that the test site (webmatrix) is hosted on my home pc, and the production site is hosted on a server farm.

Comment: Yeah.  The server farm is most likely blocking the port.  You'll probably need to check with them.